# Google Maps change style via checkboxes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I try to dynamically change style of a google maps via checkboxes.
Some control colors of features, some controls visibility. I dont get how to sum up features of styles as they are not strings. 
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var map;
      function initialize() {
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.450, 30.522);
          myOptions = {
              zoom: 5,
              center: myLatLng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions)
      }

      //checkboxes operation
      $(window).load(function(){
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
            var selected = $("input:checked").map(function(i,el){return el.value}).get();

            //Show in HTML result
            document.getElementById("SHOW").innerHTML = selected;
          });
      });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px;height:300px"></div>
    Clear Labels<input type="checkbox" id="chkLbl" value='{"elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" }]}'>
    <br>Clear Borders<input type="checkbox" id="chkBrd" value='featureType: "all",elementType:"geometry.stroke",stylers:[{ visibility:"on"}]'>
    <br>Change Water<input type="checkbox" id="chkBrd" value='{"featureType": "water", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" }]}'>

    <p id="SHOW"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various problems:
You don't need $(window).load, nor body onload, and I don't think the "map" jquery function nor the "get" function are what you want.
Also, you have a duplicate id for your checkboxes.

See the javascript interface for Google Maps for your processing:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map

Partially cleaned up code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var map;
      function initialize() {
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.450, 30.522);
          myOptions = {
              zoom: 5,
              center: myLatLng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions)
      }

      function setMapStyle(id) {
            var selected = $('#'+id).prop('checked');
            // set your style object based on "chkLbl","chkBrd","chkH2O" and call map.setStyle();
            $('#SHOW').html(/* whatever you're trying to show here*/);
      }

      //checkboxes operation
      $(document).ready(function () {
          initialize();
          $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            setMapStyle($(this).attr('id');
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px;height:300px"></div>
    Clear Labels<input type="checkbox" id="chkLbl" value='{"elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" }]}'>
    <br>Clear Borders<input type="checkbox" id="chkBrd" value='featureType: "all",elementType:"geometry.stroke",stylers:[{ visibility:"on"}]'>
    <br>Change Water<input type="checkbox" id="chkH2O" value='{"featureType": "water", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" }]}'>
    <p id="SHOW"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Accepted, but I am new to javascript and I guess I can not figure out how to set up style object based on "chkLbl"... so the map can not be loaded.

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest you study the documentation: for javascript objects, see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp; for Google Map API options see, for instance, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.DataOptions.

Comment: Um, didn't notice this before, but it looks like the "value" parameter for your checkboxes are actually property lists.  Probably what you want there is nothing (use id) or a simple string.  The property list needs to be constructed in the javascript code, not the html.

Comment: Thanks, understood. But what if I want to set style from html input textarea? Is this possible? (coold not find the solution from here and many elsewhere)

Comment: It would be rather confusing for the user to enter a property list, but it could be done... why not use checkboxes or text input (e.g. Enter TERRAIN:) to specify options?

Comment: I want one checkbox disable, for instance labels, the other checkbox change water color. All on roadmap.